# PHP-FPM - performance tuning and CPU usage

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, performance

I have a web application written in Laravel / PHP that is in the early stages and generally serves about **500 - 600 reqs/min**.   We use Maria DB and Redis for caching and everything is on AWS.

For events we want to promote on our platform, we send out a push notification (mobile platform) to all users which results in a roughly 2-min long traffic burst that takes us to **3.5k reqs/min**

At our current server scale, this completely bogs down the application servers' CPU which usually operate at around **10% CPU**.  The Databases and Redis clusters seem fine during this burst.

Looking at the logs, it seems all PHP-FPM worker pool processes get occupied and begin queuing up requests from the Nginx upstream.

We currently have:

- **three** m4.large servers (2 cores, 8gb RAM each)
- dynamic PHP-FPM process management, with a max of **120 child processes** (servers)on each box

My questions:

1) Should we increase the FPM pool?  It seems that memory-wise, we're probably nearing our limit

2) Should we **decrease** the FPM pool?  It seems possible that we're spinning up so many process that the CPU is getting bogged down and is unable to really complete any of them.

3) Should we simply use larger boxes with more RAM and CPU, which will allow us to add more FPM workers?

4) Is there any FPM performance tuning that we should be considering? We use Opcache, however, should we switch to static process management for FPM to cut down on the overhead of processes spinning up and down?

Comment: What other metrics have you collected during the traffic burst?

Comment: @MichaelHampton that's about all we know currently.  Redis and the DB seem to remain consistent, all the FPM processes get utilized and begin queuing up  requests, we spike to about 100% CPU across all servers.  I'm unfortunately uncertain how much memory gets used during this.

Comment: If you hit 100% CPU you probably have about the right number of workers for the CPU, it just happens to be not enough CPU (or workers) for the traffic. Time to scale up, or out. You could run four or five instances when you know a traffic spike is coming soon.

Comment: Can you do more page / resource caching? Not hitting PHP at all is the best way to reduce PHP CPU usage. Basically, PHP uses a lot of CPU. In AWS you can scale out in advance of a push notification using spot instances, which will give you a lot more capacity at relatively little cost.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks for you input. Yeah perhaps it’s just time to scale up some

Comment: @Tim it’s a JSON api for a mobile application. So, are you referring to something like CloudFront? We current don’t have anything like this implemented as I figured it was a little early. It’s also somewhat difficult since our application I’ve very real-time

Comment: You can cache in many places - CDN like CloudFront, web server, or less effective in your case but still useful in PHP you can call caching servers like Redis. Anything anonymous and not user specific should be cached. You just set up caching headers on the response, set up Nginx and CDN to cache based on them, your load should come down. If all responses are use specific then CDN / web server caching won't help you.